# Why this code is working fine at leetcode but giving segmentation fault at geeksforgeeks?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming

gfg https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subset-sum-problem2014/1

leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/

**Problem**:
Given an array arr[] of size N, check if it can be partitioned into two parts such that the sum of elements in both parts is the same.

Example

Input: N = 4
arr = {1, 5, 11, 5}
Output: YES
Explaination:
The two parts are {1, 5, 5} and {11}.

```
class Solution{
public:
static int equalPartition(int N, int arr[])
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            sum += arr[i];
            
        if (sum % 2 != 0)
             return 0;
             
        sum = sum/2;
        int row = N+1;
        int col = sum+1;
             
        int dp[row][col];
        
        for (int i=0; i<col; i++)
             dp[0][i] = 0;
             
        for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
             dp[i][0] = 1;
             
             
        for (int i=1; i<row; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<col; j++) {
                
                if ( j< arr[i-1])
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
                    
                else{
                    if(j-arr[i-1] > 0){
                         dp[i][j] =max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i-1][j-arr[i-1]]);
                    }
                    else{
                        dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
            
        return dp[row-1][col-1];
    }
};
```

Comment: If the array were `{ 1, 5, 11, -5 }` would that count as `{ 1, 5 }` and `{ 11, -5 }`? Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `int dp[row][col];` is not valid C++, (but supported by some compilers through extension). You should use some 2d wrapper around a `std::vector`.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> dp(row, std::vector<int>(col));` instead of the VLA.  Then when you do that, use `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements, for example: `dp.at(i).at(j) = dp.at(i-1).at(j);`.  I will bet that you will now receive a `std::out_of_range` exception being thrown on both of those websites.

Comment: what are the constraints of `sum` and `N`? one mistake I can find is `j-arr[i-1] > 0`, shouldn't this be `j-arr[i-1] >= 0`, but this should not lead to segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0):

So I signed up to portal out of curiosity to figure whats wrong. I was able to get correct answer with the following code. The code makes slight changes, mostly space compression.

As I suspected, the constraints for `N` (100) and sum of values in `array` (1e5) were very critical leading to segmentation fault.

Also instead of `j-arr[i-1] > 0`, it should be `j-arr[i-1] >= 0`.

**Explanation of space compression:**

We only need `i-1` th state to compute values of current state `i`, so 2 arrays of size `sum` each are enough. I keep a reference `curr` to remember which of the 2 array is to be considered current and `curr^1` would be the previous array. We can further optimize to only  single array of size `sum`, but it is out of scope of the answer.

```
int equalPartition(int N, int arr[])
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            sum += arr[i];
            
        if (sum % 2 != 0)
             return 0;
             
        sum = sum/2;
        int row = N+1;
        int col = sum+1;
        
        int dp[2][col]; // change 1
        for (int i=0; i<col; i++)
             dp[0][i] = 0;
             
        // for (int i=1; i<row; i++)
        //      dp[i][0] = 1;
        dp[0][0] = 1; // change 2, due to space compression don't need above
        int curr = 1; // change 3

        for (int i=1; i<row; i++, curr^=1) { // change 4
            for (int j=1; j<col; j++) {
                    dp[curr][j] = dp[curr^1][j]; // change 5
                    if(j-arr[curr^1] >= 0) // change 6
                         dp[curr][j] =max(dp[curr][j], dp[curr^1][j-arr[i-1]]); // change 7
            }
        }
        
        return dp[curr^1][col-1]; // change 8
    }
};
```